# Dynamic Function Args for Callback / RPC in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, rpc, variadic-functions

I need to register functions like the following in a list of functions with arguments.

```
void func1( int a , char* b ) {}
void func2( vec3f a , std::vector<float> b , double c) {}
...
```

And call them back when I receive data over network with proper arguments. I imagined va_list would solve, but it doesnt work :

```
void func1(int  a, char* b)
{
    printf("%d %s",a,b);
}
void prepare(...)
{
    va_list argList; 
    int args = 2;
    va_start(argList, args);
    ((void (*)(va_list))func1)(argList);
    va_end(argList);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    prepare(1, "huhu");
    return 0;
}
```

What is the most elegant way to solve this ?
I know std::bind / std::function has similar abilities, but the internal data is hidden deep in std I assume. I just need a few basic data types, doesnt have to be for arbitrary types. If preprocessor tricks with ##**VA_ARGS** or using templates would solve, I am also OK with that. Priority is that it is most simple to use.

Edit1 : I found that assembly can solve ( [How do I pass arguments to C++ functions when I call them from inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313271/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-c-functions-when-i-call-them-from-inline-assembly) ) - but I would prefer a more platform independent solution.

Comment: Most elegant? Make them all have the same signature and receive "const RpcMessage*" instead of them taking individual arguments. If you do your Rpc with a unified message type, it all degenerates to something like ``msg["value42"]``.  Then you could even simply use a ``std::map<>`` as your unified message type. The dispatching to different handlers would then be just another ``std::map<rpc_context_id,std::function<void(RpcMessage*)>>`` or similar.

Comment: Maybe use an existing RPC system rather than rolling your own?

Comment: Thx for the comments so far. @BitTicker This is the common way, just to pass a data blob I assume. Then the application has to take care of htons etc itself.

Comment: @KerrekSB I already took a look at RakNet which has RPCs, but its not implemented as comfortable as using simple functions.

Comment: @MarcoPolo: You could try Facebook's Thrift or Google's gRPC? The former has "natural" language bindings (using each host language's native types), the latter uses the well-established Protocol Buffers.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Seems they already come with a network interface. I am planning to use this for a game library, so needs to be UDP, asynchronous and with low latence. I plan to use enet for this purpose. Also they dont allow to register function as above naturally..

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create your own, small and ad-hoc "rpc" solution, possibly one of the major drivers for making decisions should be: 1. Minimal amount of code 2. Easy as possible.

Keeping that in mind, it is paying off to ponder, what the difference is between the following 2 scenarios:

1. "Real" RPC: The handlers shall be as you wrote with rpc-method-specific signature.
2. "Message passing": The handlers receive messages of either "end point-determined type" or simply of a unified message type.

Now, what has to be done to get a solution of type 1?

Incoming byte streams/network packets need to get parsed to some sort of message with regards to some chosen protocol. Then, using some meta-info (contract), according to { serviceContract, serviceMethod }, a specific set of data items needs to be confirmed in the packet and if present, the respective, registered handler function needs to be called.  Somewhere within that infrastructure you typically have a (likely code generated) function which does something like that:

```
void CallHandlerForRpcXYCallFoo( const RpcMessage*message )
{
     uint32_t arg0 = message->getAsUint32(0);
     // ...
     float argN = message->getAsFloat(N);
     Foo( arg0, arg1, ... argN );
}
```

All that can, of course also be packed into classes and virtual methods with the classes being generated from the service contract meta data. Maybe, there is also a way by means of some excessive template voodoo to avoid generating code and having a more generic meta-implementation. But, all that is work, real work. Way too much work to do it just for fun. Instead of doing that, it would be easier to use one of the dozens technologies which do that already.

Worth noting so far is: Somewhere within that piece of art, there is likely a (code generated) function which looks like the one given above.

Now, what has to be done to get a solution of type 2?

Less than for case 1. Why? Because you simply stop your implementation at calling those handler methods, which all take the `RpcMessage` as their single argument. As such, you can get away without generating the "make-it-look-like-a-function-call" layer above those methods.

Not only is it less work, it is also more robust in the presence of some scenarios where the contract changes. If one more data item is being added to the "rpc solution", the signature of the "rpc function" MUST change. Code re-generated, application code adapted. And that, whether or not the application needs that new data item. On the other hand, in approach 2, there are no breaking changes in the code. Of course, depending on your choices and the kind of changes in the contract, it still would break.

So, the most elegant solution is: Don't do RPC, do message passing. Preferably in a [REST-ful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) way.

Also, if you prefer a "unified" rpc message over a number of rpc-contract specific message types, you remove another reason for code bloat.

Just in case, what I say seems a bit too abstract, here some mock-up dummy code, sketching solution 2:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>

// "rpc" infrastructure (could be an API for a dll or a lib or so:

// Just one way to do it. Somehow, your various data types need 
// to be handled/represented.
class RpcVariant
{
public:
    enum class VariantType
    {
        RVT_EMPTY,
        RVT_UINT,
        RVT_SINT,
        RVT_FLOAT32,
        RVT_BYTES
    };
private:
    VariantType m_type;
    uint64_t m_uintValue;
    int64_t m_intValue;
    float m_floatValue;
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_bytesValue;

    explicit RpcVariant(VariantType type)
        : m_type(type)
    {

    }
public:
    static RpcVariant MakeEmpty()
    {
        RpcVariant result(VariantType::RVT_EMPTY);
        return result;
    }
    static RpcVariant MakeUint(uint64_t value)
    {
        RpcVariant result(VariantType::RVT_UINT);
        result.m_uintValue = value;
        return result;
    }
    // ... More make-functions

    uint64_t AsUint() const
    {
        // TODO: check if correct type...
        return m_uintValue;
    }
    // ... More AsXXX() functions

    // ... Some ToWire()/FromWire() functions...
};
typedef std::map<uint32_t, RpcVariant> RpcMessage_t;
typedef std::function<void(const RpcMessage_t *)> RpcHandler_t;

void RpcInit();
void RpcUninit();

// application writes handlers and registers them with the infrastructure. 
// rpc_context_id can be anything opportune - chose uint32_t, here.
// could as well be a string or a pair of values (service,method) or whatever.
void RpcRegisterHandler(uint32_t rpc_context_id, RpcHandler_t handler);

// Then according to taste/style preferences some receive function which uses the registered information and dispatches to the handlers...
void RpcReceive();
void RpcBeginReceive();
void RpcEndReceive();

// maybe some sending, too...
void RpcSend(uint32_t rpc_context_id, const RpcMessage_t * message);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    RpcInit();
    RpcRegisterHandler(42, [](const RpcMessage_t *message) { puts("message type 42 received."); });
    RpcRegisterHandler(43, [](const RpcMessage_t *message) { puts("message type 43 received."); });
    while (true)
    {
        RpcReceive();
    }
    RpcUninit();
    return 0;
}
```

And if `RpcMessage` then is traded, while packed in a std::shared_ptr, you can even have multiple handlers or do some forwarding (to other threads) of the same message instance. This is one particularly annoying thing, which needs yet another "serializing" in the rpc approach. Here, you simply forward the message.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The access of args inside he callback would be via message[0..n].AsUint() / as...() / etc  then as I understand. This is not bad but not yet the convenient solution I am looking for.

Comment: @MarcoPolo Trust me - the "convenient solution" stops being really convenient once your system gets bigger. Once you are stuck in your RPC functions but you end up having multiple worker threads, it quickly gets rather inconvenient as you have the same problem again. Also, rpc style enforces ALL data of the message to be extracted (to fill in the arguments). Also, what when you will have a message with 50 items? function with 50 args?